# How many bytes are typically loaded into memory when using file.seek() in python?

Tags: python, file, hash, size, seek

I'm currently using a 4 Giga-byte sized file as Open-addressing Hash table.
In order to read each offset I'm using file.seek() function for a 1-byte (char) data. I want to optimize the size of the file using buckets (saving up space on offsets that have no data), for the optimization to be best I want to know how much bytes are cached into memory when ever I am using file.seek()?
That way I can tune the buckets so the file will require less space but the disk I/O reads won't increase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file.seek()` approach will be very memory efficient but also very slow. You will want to align everything by the page boundary though, thus I suggest that you do not cross the 4 kiB boundaries.

Instead of using `file.seek()`, if you are using 64-bit processor, map the entire file in memory using [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html). Then you can use the rule that pages are usually 4 kiB in size, thus aligning everything on the 4 kiB boundary. This is most certainly faster than dummily using `file.seek`; though it might end up consuming more memory, the operating system can fine tune to your access patterns.

---

On Python 3 you would use `mmap` as follows:

```
# provided that your hashtable is in this file
# and its size is 4 GiB
with open("hashtable", "r+b") as f:
    # memory-map the file, size 0 means whole file
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)

    # here mm behaves like 4 billion element bytearray
    # that you can read from and write to. changes
    # are flushed to the underlying file.

    # set 1 byte in the file
    mm[123456789] = 42

    # ensure that changes are written to disk
    mm.flush()

    # close the mapping
    mm.close()
```

Comment: I would encourage the use `mmap` too. Do you know if there are some mechanism to explicitly *unload* some pages when their are no longer required ? The default OS cache strategy is not necessary suitable in the OP particular use case...

Comment: Unfortunately the exact specifics of cache flushing are OS specific, would need to call `madvise` on Linux; certainly doable with `ctypes`.

Comment: I will consider your offering to use mmap instead. but unfortunately I think it won't help me, since I am dealing with 40 files as described above, each of them can size from 100MB to 4GB, so loading all of them to the memory can be some what unfeasible, and I will use the swap partition way too much.
Also loading all the files can take really long time (it takes about 10-30 minutes to load all of them to memory).

Regarding OS, currently the code runs on Windows-7, But I will soon need to set it up on a dedicated linux (probably centos) server.

Comment: No, they will not use swap, they will use the *file*. This is also the approach used by MongoDB for the entire database (the *entire* database is mmapped at all times).